# Can I create global interceptor in Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, unity-container, aop

In Unity, I can achieve global interceptor easily like this...

```
container.Configure<Interception>().AddPolicy("mylog")
    .AddMatchingRule<SomeMatchingRule>() // always return true
    .AddCallHandler<LoggingCallhandler>();
```

However, I cannot find a way for Autofac to make a global interceptor. At the moment I can only add intercept to all registration one by one like thie...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
       .EnableClassInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggingInterceptor));
builder.Register(c => new LoggingInterceptor());
```

Looking for anyone to save me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac doesn't support this sort of feature out of the box. You *may be able to* write something [as middleware in the resolve pipeline](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/pipelines.html) to glue the logic from Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy into the pipeline but there's nothing just ready to go.

Emphasis on *may be able to* because I haven't done it, either. That's just the road I'd start looking at. No guarantees it leads to fruition.

Comment: I tried your solution and partially work, but only for Enabling Interface Interceptor part. For Enabling Class Interceptor, I have no luck, as I found that the underly mechanism of enabling class interceptor is done and ended in `IRegistrationBuilder` phase, i.e. there are some snippet - `registration.ActivatorData.ImplementationType = xxx` which cannot be amended once entering request resolve pipeline. Do you have any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.